# Possible to control Adobe Professional 9 through win32ole API?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, win32ole

As the title says.. Is it possible to control Adobe Professional 9 through the win32ole API, preferably by using Ruby scripts.

I want to be able to open a PDF document and enable the extended commenting features allowing for commenting the file when opened in Adobe Reader, but I need to do it programmatically.

~ ToRd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to control adobe professional through the win32ole API. However, it is not trivial, due to the lack of descriptive API information. A co-worker of mine were able to achieve what I needed by using Delphi.